# Вывод несколько данных в одном textbox(c# - windows forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Одна кнопка сортирует пузырьком и вставкой. Как сделать, чтобы она выводила оба результата в один `textbox`?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] mass_1 = new int[razmer_1]; int temp, index, chislo;

            for (int i = 0; i < razmer_1; i++) { mass_1[i] = random.Next(nach_chislo_1, end_chislo_1); }
            for (int i = 0;i < razmer_1; i++) { iznach_1 += mass_1[i] + " "; }
            textBox7.Text = iznach_1.ToString();

            //Сортировка пузырьком
            for (int i = 0; i < mass_1.Length; i++)   //Сортировка пузырьком
            {
                for (int j = 0;  j < mass_1.GetLength(0) - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (mass_1[j] > mass_1[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = mass_1[ j ]; mass_1[ j ] = mass_1[ j + 1 ]; mass_1[ j + 1 ] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < razmer_1; i++) { rez_1 += mass_1[i] + " "; }
            textBox8.Text = "Сортировка пузырьком: " + Environment.NewLine + rez_1.ToString();

            textBox8.Text =  Environment.NewLine;
            //Сортировка вставками
            for (int i = 0; i < mass_1.Length; i++)
            {
                index = i; chislo = mass_1[i];
                while (index > 0 && chislo < mass_1[index - i])
                {
                    mass_1[index] = mass_1[index - 1]; index --;
                }
                mass_1[index] = chislo;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < razmer_1; i++) { rez_1_1 += mass_1[i] + " "; }
            textBox8.Text = "Сортировка вставками: " + Environment.NewLine + rez_1_1.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Не забывайте метку winforms добавлять

Answer (score 0):

Меняем последнюю строку

```
 textBox8.Text =  textBox8.Text + " Сортировка вставками: " +  rez_1_1.ToString();
```

Environment.NewLine не используем в textBox.
TextBox это в 1 строку.
Environment.NewLine  используем если texbox multiline = true.

Comment: у меня стоит texbox multiline = true

Comment: ну тогда такое   textBox8.Text =  textBox8.Text + ....   должно работать

Comment: `rez_1_1.ToString()` - при конкатенации ToString() не нужно вызывать явно, оно и так будет работать